# Error for uploading image for live the app on iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to live the app via iTunes, but when uploading the image(s), this error shows:

> The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong.

What are the sizes for uploading for iPhone 3.5, 4, 4.7 and 5.5 inches?

Comment: Apple has its own documentation for screenshot sizes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshots of the iPhone6plus simulator and upload your images. Remember to press command+1 to let the simulator screen 100%, and then press command+s screenshot.

Comment: What is the size of app Icon for live the app.

Comment: Size for app icon is 1024 x 1024

Answer (score 0):

The following resolutions are acceptable to iTunes connect:

- iPhone 5 (4 Inch)

  - 640 x 1136
- iPhone 6 (4.7 Inch)

  - 750 x 1334
- iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 Inch)

  - 1242 x 2208
- iPad (Air and Mini Retina)

  - 1536 x 2048
- iPad Pro

  - 2048 x 2732
- Apple Watch

  - 312 x 390 pixels

Make sure your screenshots follow these dimensions.

Size of app icon: 1024 x 1024

There is an update in iTunes known as `Media manager` in which you need to upload screenshots of just `5.5 inch` & media manager will take care of rest of the sizes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
iPhone 3+4 (3.5 Inch)
640 x 960
iPhone 5 (4 Inch)
640 x 1136
iPhone 6 (4.7 Inch)
750 x 1334
iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 Inch)
1242 x 2208
You need the screenshot in this resolution, the phone scales them down to 1080 x 1920
iPad (Air and Mini Retina)
1536 x 2048
iPad Pro
2048 x 2732
Apple Watch
312 x 390 pixels
(only one orientation)
```